# How to retrieve rest let data from suitelet and print in execution logs

Tags: netsuite

How to retrieve rest let data from suitelet and print in execution logs. I have wrote a restlet script i'm able to see the output in postman. I need those output in suitelet script.
below is the suitelet script which i have tried.

```
function callRestletData(request,response)
{
    try
    {
        url = 'https://tstdrxxxxxx.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=xxx&deploy=1';
        //orderId = 741;
        var hearders = {};
        hearders['Authorization'] = 'NLAuth nlauth_account=TSTDRVxxxx, nlauth_email=abc@abc.com, nlauth_signature=xxxxxx, nlauth_role=3';
        hearders['contentType'] = 'application/json';
        //var myResponse = https.post(myRequest);
        var myResopnse = nlapiRequestURL(url,null,hearders,null,'GET');
        
        //var responseText = myResopnse.getBody();
        var data = JSON.stringify(myResopnse);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Response Is:',data);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR','In Catch Block',error.message);
    }
}
```